# Changing Linear Units on Scale Bar to a unit not listed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, units, scale-bar, mapview

In ArcMap, how can I change my linear units on a scale bar for layout view to a unit not listed on the drop down menu in units of the scale bar?  I want to get survey chains in my map as a scale bar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom scalebar units in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328/custom-scalebar-units-in-arcmap)

Comment: It sort of does.  But I am still somewhat new to ArcMap.  I can't quite figure out what the copy the projection means and so forth.  I found a deal that said Linear Units as Meters but I couldn't edit it.  Now I can't even find that again.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Data Frame Properties and go to the Coordinate System tab. Right click on the currently highlighted coordinate system and select 'Copy and Modify'. This will open a dialog that will allow you to define a new coordinate system with a custom linear unit.

[image]

Several variants of chain are available from the drop down, but you can also select 'custom' and simply enter in the conversion factor from meters. Make sure your data frame is set to this new custom coordinate system and then insert your scale bar. You will get a warning about an about needing to define the data frame units, just ignore it. The scale bar will still be labelled as 'meters' - you can manually change that label in the scale bar properties

[image]